# concatenate string and integer to produce byte array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a std string and and long that I want to concatenate to produce a byte array (unsigned char *). I have no clue how to do it in c++, I struggled trying to do it with memory.

In java System.arraycopy does the trick.

here are my inputs :

```
unsigned long  part1   = 0x0100000002;
std::string part2  = "some_str";
```

what i want to have is unsigned `char * combined = part2 + part1`

any hint ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: *why* do you want them to be in a "byte array"?

Comment: it'is required for transmission protocol and to respect the standard for that protocol.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but here's one using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to hold the destination buffer (and manage all the memory allocation and deallocation associated with it) and [`std::memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (which is similar to `System.arraycopy`) to do the copying.

```
  unsigned long  part1 = 0x0100000002;
  std::string part2 = "some_str";

  // create a vector big enough to hold both components
  std::vector<char> buffer(sizeof(part1) + part2.size());

  // copy the string into the beginning of the buffer
  std::memcpy(&buffer[0], &part2[0], part2.size());
  // copy the int into the space after the string
  std::memcpy(&buffer[part2.size()], &part1, sizeof(part1));

  std::cout.write(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
  std::cout << "\n";
```

You can get a plain old `char*` pointer from a `std::vector<char>` by doing things like `&buffer[0]`, which gets a pointer to the first element in the underlying array that makes up the vector. You may need to handle your own null termination, if you wanted to use this like a string (which is why I used `std::cout.write` instead of `std::cout <<` in my example).

An alternative that avoids using memcpy and having to handle the buffer size yourself is to use a stream:

```
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss.write(&part2[0], part2.size());
  ss.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&part1), sizeof(part1));

  std::string buf = ss.str();

  std::cout.write(buf.c_str(), buf.size());
  std::cout << "\n";
```

As output on windows from either version, I get this:

> some_str☻

Comment: A downvote without comment is entirely pointless and unhelpful. If you can't explain what the problem with the answer is, you aren't going to get an improved one and so nobody will benefit.

Comment: You shouldn't had answered an _off-topic_ question at all. That simple.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ahh, so you vote to _punish_, not to signify whether an answer is bad or good. Gotcha. Sensible policy. Good to see someone sticking to the rules, eh?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ let's assume it's off topic you should at least clarify why and punish people for being helpful :)

Comment: @user3291059 if it _were_ off topic, there's a perfectly good flagging and close-voting system that's separate to the question/answer quality score system that's intended to deal with such things.  πάντα ῥεῖ has been here long enough to know that.